# How to remove all .php extension from a dir and all of its subdirectories?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My web is dir structured is as follows :

> moving/
>             includes/
>             controllers/
>             includes/
>             etc...

I have the following questions about `/moving` and all of its sub-diretories:

1. How can i request any php script without the .php extension?
2. How can i request `...dir/index.php?q=about` as just `...dir/about`?
3. Where woul i place my .htaccess file?

I understand that my first question *might* be a duplicate, but in order to contextualize my second and third question i had to ask it.

Using WampServer 2.0
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apache will not parse your php script if they don't have the ".php" extention.

but, you can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.htmlinternal):

> This module uses a rule-based
>   rewriting engine (based on a
>   regular-expression parser) to rewrite
>   requested URLs on the fly. It supports
>   an unlimited number of rules and an
>   unlimited number of attached rule
>   conditions for each rule, to provide a
>   really flexible and powerful URL
>   manipulation mechanism. The URL
>   manipulations can depend on various
>   tests, of server variables,
>   environment variables, HTTP headers,
>   or time stamps. Even external database
>   lookups in various formats can be used
>   to achieve highly granular URL
>   matching.
>
> This module operates on the full URLs
>   (including the path-info part) both in
>   per-server context (httpd.conf) and
>   per-directory context (.htaccess) and
>   can generate query-string parts on
>   result. The rewritten result can lead
>   to internal sub-processing, external
>   request redirection or even to an
>   internal proxy throughput.internal proxy throughput.

Comment: "apache will not parse your php script if they don't have the ".php" extention.": What are you talking about? Apache can serve any file extension as PHP if you modify either the config or .htaccess file with `AddType`.

Comment: I should have added "by default" :)

Answer (score 1):

If all your website files are ending with .php and you want to take off the .php extension, then you should create and .htaccess file, or if you already have it, add this rule:

## RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]

Supposing your website pages are let's say site/about.php, site/contact.php, site/news.php, the rule above will just transform those to site/about, site/contact, site/news

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have mod_rewrite routing non-php extension request to the proper request, you would put it in your root web directory.