# Dynamic url in php without filename

Tags: php, dynamic

I couldn't find exact answer to my question so I am posting this. Maybe it involves htaccess configuring.

What I would like is to have http://www.example.com/static_folder/dynamic_parameter

the above url should run the index.php in static_folder and I should be able to get that dynamic_parameter and output accordingly.

How to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just do a search for 'clean urls php'. The internet (including Stack Overflow) is full of tutorials that explain you how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A littlebit of htaccess can do it pretty easily. As for example, save this rule in the root directory's htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/static_folder/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /static_folder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` inside `/static_folder/index.php` to get the dynamic_parameter.
Is it what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

then you can do:

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Also check answers for this question: [How to remove all .php extension from a dir and all of its subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321214/how-to-remove-all-php-extension-from-a-dir-and-all-of-its-subdirectories)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the OP asked for index.php inside static_folder to get the variable, so, something like this, should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^static_folder/([^/]+)$ static_folder/index.php?variable=1$ [NC,L]
```