# Directory/file names confusion

Tags: directory

I wasn't sure how to word this but the easiest way to describe what I mean is just by giving an example.

Take this site -> http://lolprofile.net/summoner/lan/rimortix . When you search for a summoner the user in this case `rimortix` changes but the page renders the same just with a different users info. They don't use index.php?user=rimortix which would make sense to me on how it would work. How do they dynamically query for user info in this url layout?

The site I used was just an example but I have seen this same layout many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this and it was exactly what I was going for.

[Dynamic url in php without filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176270/dynamic-url-in-php-without-filename)